# Asp .Net client side dynamic text

Tags: html, asp.net

Im learning Asp.Net, after writing a master page, I couldnt make it run on client (to actually see the animation). The thread waiting action is done on server before publishing the web page so animation is not dynamic. It shows only the final state of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="red">
<center>
    <h2>Hello w3schools!</h2>
    <h4 id="aa">qq</h4>
    <h3>

        <p><% 


           for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
           {
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
               int txtLeft = 300 + (int)(100*Math.Sin(i));
               int txtTop = 300+(int)(100*Math.Cos(i));
               string theText = "Hello there!";
               Response.Write("<div style=\"position:absolute; left: "+ txtLeft + "px; top:" + txtTop + "px; \">" + theText +"</div>");
           }

           %></p>


    </h3>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried

> runat="client"   (near the "p" letter  which is in brackets)

but it failed:

Runat must have value Server.

[image]

Comment: Use javascript and make it work on the client and use the server just to serve the page. If you really want to generate the HTML server-side, use the asp.net literal control, not response.write.

Comment: You mean, I need to write actual code in the aspx file instead of master file?

Comment: I mean use javascript and jquery; put the code that's in your for-loop in a javascript function and make it run with jQuery on document.ready

Comment: Is position:absolute a javascript or jQuery thing or HTML CSS here?

Comment: It's a CSS definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [**jsFiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/rMUb9/)

```
$(Start);

function Start() {

    var txtLeft, txtTop, theText, theHTML;

    theText = "Hello there!";

    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        txtLeft = 300 + (100 * Math.sin(i));
        txtTop = 300 + (100 * Math.cos(i));

        theHTML = '<div style="position:absolute; left: ' + txtLeft + 'px; top:' + txtTop + 'px;">' + theText + '</div>';

        $('#Demo').append(theHTML);
    }
}
```

Basically, there's no need for server-side programming to generate the output you want; use asp.net for server work. What you can do is add this script to the page in a `script` tag along with the jquery reference and you're done.

Comment: yes, you can modify it using setTimeout to make it wait and call back after a certain time.